# constexpr array vs deque, memory utilization

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constants, c++14

I need to store a pre-known size of about 30 integers in my code, I have gone for

```
constexpr std::array<size_t, 30> MAPPING{1, 2, 3, ...};
```

If i am not wrong, the above will be evaluated at compile time, but it would also take up a single sequential block of memory of a size of 30 integers?

If it does, is it worth using a std::deque instead

```
const std::deque<int> MAPPING{1, 2, 3, ...};
```

This way, with a deque, we would not be using a single large sequential memory block and it might use a bunch of fragmented blocks instead and thus it will work fine even if the memory is fragmented?

Please let me know if I have missed anything, thanks

Comment: array is always a contiguous block of memory. it is fixed size (i.e. it's size is known at compile time)
A deque is a dynamic container, it can grow in size at runtime.

Deque uses dynamic allocation for it's contents (every item is allocated on a different location), while array does not if you don't allocate it yourself on the dynamic storage.

Comment: Why do you even consider a dequeue if you already know the size ?

Comment: IMO fragmentation for such a small allocation isn't worth worrying about. Use the `array`. Besides the `deque` will use more memory as it has bookkeeping to do that it needs memory for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not worth using `std::deque` here.

*It would also take up a single sequential block of memory of a size of 30 integers?*

---

Yes, it would take up a single sequential block of memory of a size of 30 integers **in the stack**

*This way, with a deque, we would not be using a single large sequential memory block and it might use a bunch of fragmented blocks instead and thus it will work fine even if the memory is fragmented?*

---

It's [implementation-dependent](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), for 30 integers they may be split into several small blocks or may not, but it will use **heap** memory and thus has runtime overhead:

> As opposed to std::vector, the elements of a deque are not stored
> contiguously: typical implementations use a sequence of individually
> allocated fixed-size arrays, with additional bookkeeping, which means
> indexed access to deque must perform two pointers dereferences,
> compared to vector's indexed access which performs only one.

According to @Homer512's comment, we also need to notice the memory fragmentation when using the heap, there may be memory waste and we can't avoid it.

Comment: Good answer. I haven't checked VC, but gcc uses fixed blocks of 512 byte for its deque. Or 128 integers. Maybe worth noting. I'd also add that heap fragmentation is much less of a problem now than it had been historically. Especially in 64bit it's not worth worrying about it

Comment: @Homer512 Thank you for such a great supplement! I would like to reference your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clarification, I understand now :-)